# Did Hamar and other priests die with Nellifer?

Tags: land-of-the-pharaohs

In the 1955 film *Land of Pharaohs*, the high priest Hamar lures Princess Nellifer to Pharoh Khufu's tomb so that she can possess the treasures and becomes the Queen of Egypt; but in fact he is going to bury her there because of her betrayal. He tells her to push something that breaks the sand jars and closes the stone gates. She then begs for her life to no avail.

They all seem trapped inside. So are Hamar and other priests also going to die there?

Answer (score -1):

> I believe that Hamar intends to
>
> be sealed in the tomb with Pharaoh.
>
> He and the mute priests.
>
> I can only presume it will be
>
> the same for Senta and myself.

https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=the_land_of_the_pharaohs_20609&p=25

> - What is this?

> - The tomb is being sealed, Your Majesty.
>
> oh, no.
>
> No.
>
> Show me the way out, I command you.
>
> - Show me the way.
> - There's no way out.
>
> This is what you lied and

> schemed and murdered to achieve.
>
> - This is your kingdom.

https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=the_land_of_the_pharaohs_20609&p=26

> - No, no!
>
> I don't wanna die. I don't wanna die!
>
> I don't want to die, please help me!
>
> I don't want to die.

https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=the_land_of_the_pharaohs_20609&p=27

This a transcript of the dialog and not a copy of the actual script with directions.

> Once she gives the order to seal the sarcophagus, the jars of sand are broken, and massive stone blocks seal the way out. "There's no way out!" Hamar tells her. "This is what you lied and schemed and murdered to achieve. This is your kingdom!" Nellifer vainly screams for mercy as she, Hamar and the priests who accompanied them are interred in the tomb.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Pharaohs#Plot

The people who answer this question:

https://moviechat.org/tt0048283/Land-of-the-Pharaohs/58c705f54e1cf308b93709fb/Please-tell-how-it-ended

all assume that Hamar and the priests are trapped inside the tomb with Nellifer.

If Hamar and the mute priests left by a secret passageway what would stop Nellifer from following them?  They could kill her or tie her up before revealing the secret passageway but I didn't notice any weapons or rope in the scene.

And even if they put one stone in front of the entrance to the secret passageway someone might notice that the pyramid sounded hollow when tapped at that spot, or that the stone looked loosely placed, and break through the stone to find an otherwise empty passage to the tomb chamber.

And possible would be tomb robbers might watch all sides of the pyramid and might notice the priests leaving and go to where they put the stone in place cioving the exit to the secret passageway.

Of course the exit to the secret passageway would have been an obvious passageway for everyone to notice for years until Hamar and the priests lowered the last stone to cover the exit.

I can't think of any way for Hamar and the priests to get out of the tomb while keeping Nellifer inside without murdering her before they leave, which would certainly change the tone of the movie.

Comment: This answer seems to be little more than a badly formatted transcript of the film and some assertions about what might have happened.

Answer (score -2):

## Yes

As mentioned at Wikipedia

> the jars of sand are broken, and massive stone blocks seal the way out. "There's no way out!" Hamar tells her. "This is what you lied and schemed and murdered to achieve. This is your kingdom!" **Nellifer vainly screams for mercy as she, Hamar and the priests who accompanied them are interred in the tomb.**

Comment: This appears to be written by a fan, rather than anyone connected with the film itself.